# CCK For joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla, cck, joomla1.6

I need a recommendation for a CCK(More Applocation builder) module for joomla 1.6.
these are my needs.

1. Muliti language support(include rtl).
2. Form builder that allows create multiple content nodes (Like Articles).
3. Well documented and simple API for template side.
4. Fields such as: image,upload,movie,rich text and date.
5. I saw that drupal CCK creates table per field, I would like to avoid that.

I don't mind paying for such module.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, only 3 of the reputable CCK components have released a 1.6 version so far -

Zoo - http://www.yootheme.com/zoo/ (must be version 2.4, not on JED yet)

Seblod - http://www.seblod.com/ (used to be JSeblod, is only at RC stage right now)

K2 - http://getk2.org/ (still in beta, but you can get it from their SVN)